# Can you override the variable definition inside closures?

Tags: swift, scope, closures

The code example comes from the [swift office document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94)

```
let digitNames = [
    0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two",   3: "Three", 4: "Four",
    5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"
]
let numbers = [16, 58, 510]

let strings = numbers.map {
    (number) -> String in
    var number = number //What is this!
    var output = ""
    while number > 0 {
        output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
        number /= 10
}    
    return output
}
```

I'm very confuse about the line `var number = number` inside the closure body. How can you "re-declare" a variable with the same scope?

Comment: In `(number) -> String` the `number` parameter is a constant. So you make a var from it and it becomes mutable. In the scope, the mutable one is used, the other is ignored. This kind of "redeclaration" only works with function parameters, within the scope of the function.

Comment: @EricD: That works also in other local scopes, not only with function parameters.

Comment: @MartinR Anything changed in Swift 3 regarding this property?

Comment: @MartinR Ah, yes, thanks. And that's why I made a comment instead of a complete answer, I was afraid to miss or mess something... and I did. :)

Comment: by the way, it's exactly what `if let var = var` or `guard let var = var else` are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants or variables defined in a scope can use the same name
as another constant/variable defined in the outer scope. In that case,
the local variable "hides" the outer one, but only after its definition.
The initial value of the new variable can refer to the outer variable
with the same name. Example:

```
func foo() {
    let x = 5
    do {
        var x = x
        //      ^-- The value of the outer constant `x`
        //  ^------ The local variable x
        x += 1
        print(x) // 6
    }
    print(x) // 5
}
```

A common use-case is to make a "variable copy" of a function parameter:

```
func digitsum(n : Int) -> Int {
    var s = 0
    var n = n
    while n > 0 {
        s += n % 10
        n /= 10
    }
    return s
}
```

and the same happens in your closure:

```
let strings = numbers.map {
    (number) -> String in
    var number = number
    //           ^-- The number that the closure was called with
    //  ^----------- A local variable `number`
    var output = ""
    while number > 0 {
        output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
        number /= 10
    }    
    return output
}
```

Of course you could also choose a different name for the local variable.

In earlier Swift versions, you could declare a function parameter
as a variable:

```
func digitsum(var n : Int) -> Int
```

but that feature was deprecated in Swift 2.2 and will be removed
in Swift 3.